# How to get the datagrid cell values with column name on row double click Instead of item array index?

Tags: c#

**How to get the `datagrid` cell values with column name on row double click**, instead of item array index?

I generate columns with query:

```
private void grid_supplier_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (grid_supplier.SelectedItem == null) return;
    DataRowView dr = grid_supplier.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
    DataRow dr1 = dr.Row;

    txt_hiden_edit_id.Text = Convert.ToString(dr1.ItemArray[0]);
    comb_supplier_name.SelectedValue = Convert.ToString(dr1.ItemArray[1]);
    datepicker_supplier.SelectedDate = DateTime.Parse(Convert.ToString(dr1.ItemArray[2]));
    txt_payment.Text = Convert.ToString(dr1.ItemArray[3]);
    txt_reciept_number.Text = Convert.ToString(dr1.ItemArray[4]);

    txt_quantity.Text = Convert.ToString(dr1.ItemArray[5]);
    txt_code.Text = Convert.ToString(dr1.ItemArray[6]);
}
```

Comment: This code is working fine but I want cell values with name instead of cell index.

Comment: Is this WinForms or WPF?

Comment: Perhaps it doesnt make a difference, but why arent you using `sender`?  I believe that it only gives you the row, not the cell, but it seems like a bad practice to go get the datagrid from inside your event handler.